# Outlook 2003: How to group by flag AND sort by date?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2003, sorting, combine, flag

I'm trying to get Outlook 2003 to do the following:

Group the emails in my Inbox by FLAG and then sort by DATE.

This SHOULD be accomplished by the following settings:

[image]

It seems to work, as I get groups and WITHING the "unflaggeed" part, I see the items properly sorted:

[image]

But having a look in detail, the SORTING within the flagged items is broken/odd to say the least:

[image]

Any idea of what might be the issue here? I've tried using "custom" configuration in the view, and the settings that I have seem to be what SHOULD work:

[image]

But the odd behaviour persists. And this is impacting my way of working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the "Customize View" window, "Group By" should be "Flag Status" (as you have it shown).  However, try changing "Sort" to "'Flag Status' then 'Received'", as shown below:

[image: Outlook Grouping and Sorting]

This makes it show up the way I think you're expecting it to (see below):

[image: Mail sorted properly]