# How to sort mail by followup flag then conversation by date? (Outlook-2007)

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

I have a question that is similar to but not [Outlook 2003: How to group by flag AND sort by date?](https://superuser.com/questions/57864/outlook-2003-how-to-group-by-flag-and-sort-by-date) I want to have my inbox arranged by the flag status first, but after that have them grouped by conversation with the most recently active conversation at the top.

If I Group By Flag Status Descending then conversation the conversation is sorted by subject not received date.

If I group by flag status then sort by Conversation Index Descending, the conversations are roughly grouped by time but only from the first one and they do not have the group by collapse function.

Is there any way to get the behavior of the normal 'arrange by conversation' but to only do so within the flag statuses?

Comment: Same question here. Did you figure it out @Doug-W? (Your question is from 12 years ago, but I have the same question now. Hope you have an answer after 12 years, cannot find an answer elsewhere)